# Prove/Disprove that you can't draw an X inside a box without lifting the pen

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, eulerian-path

I apologize if this is a repost, but I couldn't find the question in case it does actually exist here.

I tried and it seems to me that we cannot draw a square with its diagonals without lifting the pen off the paper.

How do you mathematically prove or disprove this claim?

Comment: It does depend upon the font you use.

Comment: Usual argument:  Imagine such a path.  It either starts and stops at the same vertex or it doesn't. If it does, then each vertex would have evenly many edges reaching it, which is not the case here.  If it doesn't, then exactly $2$ vertices would have an odd number of edges reaching it , which is also false.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  You seem to be missing crucial information such as whether or not you are allowed to retrace your path and reuse edges... I can very easily draw a box with an $x$ inside... start by tracing the perimeter of a square having started and ended at a vertex... then draw the diagonal, then trace along one of the edges you had previously drawn, and finish by drawing the remaining diagonal... all without lifting your pen off the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is an Eulerian path (that is to say, a path through a graph that visits every single edge) in the complete graph $K_4$ (the graph with four vertices, in which every vertex is connected).

It is a known property of Eulerian paths that one exists only if there are either exactly zero or exactly two vertices with odd degree (the degree of a vertex is the number of edges it has).

In the graph $K_4$, all four vertices have degree three. Three is an odd number, and thus there are four vertices of odd degree. Thereby, we know that there is no Eulerian path through this particular graph.